# Same data is being recieved again and again while following 'paging' facebook php sdk 3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, inbox

Using php sdk 3, I am trying to follow the links in the **paging** array which as something like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/2015469353355/comments?limit=9999&until=1325376000&__paging_token=2015469353355_176&access_token=AAAFfJS6rRAABADxi04SdFJzdAKPAxRi6rprZCZBZAZAkAO0kQWD7sUQKZCVAhbzZBgaUa5ogrKHvuO3iZA0F2VBHVxWa6Sg17suL0capzCizncaEQZBxxxxx
```

I use loop to get next five pages of data. Every thing is working fine but the same data is returned five times.

To get around the problem, I changed **until=1341100800** with **until=1325376000**.
But the results are again repeating(though they are now different data relating to changed time).

Comment: Have you tried using since and until instead of limit? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Yes i tried both since and until